# Azure Data Factory ForEach is seemingly not running data flow in parallel

Tags: azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory I am using a Lookup activity to get a list of files to download, then pass it to a ForEach where a dataflow is processing each file

I do not have 'Sequential' mode turned on, I would assume that the data flows should be running in parallel. However, their runtimes are not the same but actually have almost constant time between them (like, first data flow ran 4 mins, second 6, third 8 and so on). It seems as if the second data flow is waiting for the first one to finish and then uses its cluster to process the file.

Is that intended behavior? I have TTL on the cluster set but that did not help too much. If it is, then what is a workaround? I am currently working on creating a list of files first and using that instead of a ForEach but I am not sure if I am going to see an increase in efficiency

Comment: I [did read somewhere](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/pipeline-trigger-troubleshoot-guide#foreach-activities-do-not-run-in-parallel-mode) that if you are running in Debug mode (ie from the UX) then For Each might not run in parallel, and you see a warning to this effect.  Can you please confirm if you are running in Debug mode or looking at the logs for triggered runs?

Comment: Yes that was also an idea of mine and I published and triggered my pipeline to check and the issue remains. What happens is that foreach starts around 20 dataflows at once (did not count), but one is running and others are stuck on "Acquiring compute"

Comment: Hmm interesting, you might try reducing the concurrency of the For Each loop to experiment.  Although it may seem counter-intuitive, a little bit of throttling is not unusual in parallel workflows and you may be overwhelming your compute.   If you've got time, try sequential mode to get a baseline timing, then raise concurrency, 2, 3, 5 etc.  There is probably a 'sweet spot' for your workload.  Alternately, try a bigger cluster.

Comment: As an experiment, I increased the size of the cluster (16-16) and set the Batch count to 2. The result was the same - 2 data flows would fire at the same time, the first one would finish in 3 minutes (1 minute waiting for the cluster, 2 minutes processing) and the second in 5 minutes (I guess, 3 minutes waiting for the first data flow, 2 minutes processing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to solve the issue with the Parallel data flows not executing in parallel, however, I have managed to change the solution that would increase performance.

What was before: A lookup activity that would get a list of files to process, passed on to a ForEach loop with a data flow activity.

What I am testing now: A Data flow activity that would get a list of files, and save them in a text file in ADLS, Then another data flow activity that was previously in a ForEach loop, but changed its source to use "List of Files" and point to that list

The result was an increase in efficiency (Using the same cluster, 40 files would take around 80 mins using ForEach and only 2-3 mins using List of Files), however, debugging is not easy now that everything is in 1 data flow

You can overwrite a list of files file, or use dynamic expressions and name the file as the pipelineId or something else

Comment: can you share the logic of passing list of files in dataflow